# How to mark an empty value in a line of a text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, emptydatatext

I am working on a script fragment which has the task of reading a file version from a line in a text file, *(the output from sigcheck.exe)*:

```
    File version:   130.120.20.02
```

The problem occurs when the value is empty:

```
    File version:
```

After the colon there is a tab and many spaces.

I try to use the command `IF`:

```bash
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2* delims=:  *" %%n in (FileVer.txt) do (
    (
        @echo %%n
    )
    if "%%n"=="" (
        @echo ouu there's nothing here  & pause
    ) else (
        do something else...
    )
)
```

I don't want to specify the number of spaces, (even though it works), because it will probably be different every time.

I've tried:
"[]", "", " ", "null" and nothing. It often appears: `ECHO is off.`

I can't find anywhere how to mark null characters, or rather many spaces instead of characters.

Comment: put the TAB and SPACE at the very end of the delimiters and skip the `*`. Wildcards are not supported here. Concurrent delimiters are treated as one, so SPACE` will delimit at each occurrence of "one or more spaces". `"tokens=2* delims=:  "`

Comment: And `delims=<TAB><SPACE>` will delimit on each occurrence of any combination of tabs and spaces.

Comment: `echo(%%n` avoids the `echo is OFF` when `%%n` is empty.

Comment: Based upon your `FileVer.txt` name, it implies that you are using `sigcheck.exe` yourself, just to determine the file version information, outputting that to the text file, then reading that file. I have to ask therefore, if you are aware that you can perform that task directly without the need for the intermediate text file?

Comment: I suppose I should also mention that in my experience with using Sigcheck, if there is no version information to retrieve, the output is always `n/a`. Therefore based upon your question content, it is not currently possible for us to produce a text file or output using that tool which looks like that which you've submitted.

Comment: Here's some one line examples: **1.** Asking for output in CSV format; ```@For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=9 Delims=," %%G In ('^""P:\athTo\sigcheck.exe" -c "P:\athTo\YourExeFile.exe" -NoBanner 2^>NUL^"') Do @Echo(%%~G```. **2.** Asking only for the file version information; ```@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""P:\athTo\sigcheck.exe" -n "P:\athTo\YourExeFile.exe" -NoBanner 2^>NUL^"') Do @Echo(%%G```

Comment: Using the former CSV output method, if somebody has deliberately inserted one or more spaces or horizotal tabs it the version field, (rather than leaving it blank for a `n/a` result), then `%%G`, which would already be doublequoted, and would still hold those. In that case, you should be able to parse/compare it in your subsequent code.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your replies and help.
Especially thank you @Compo for the valuable tips.
A good point about skipping the output to the text file. However, as a beginner, I figured it would be easier for me to format the output by reading the first line of the text file, where I could more easily spot spaces and other characters. I write this code a little bit out of passion, a little bit in my spare time. Thanks a lot for your help. I was simply annoyed by files called "setup.exe", which I did not know what they were for.

Comment: The main point I was making @M4L3_2024, is that the program `sigcheck.exe` is not outputting a series of spaces when, in your own words, "the value is empty". It will only output the content of the field as whitespace if the developer has themselves inserted those spaces in that field. I have seen a few examples with one or more leading spaces, and many with trailing spaces, but so far none with only spaces.